# Scary Sync Issue

Tags: video-reference, sync

Hello again everyone!

I'm back from my last gig and I had something happen that was scary that I hope some of you can help me with and that was:

Specs:
Pro Tools HD recording,
Locked to Word Clock set at 96K, and Video Reference (black burst) from the video truck realm.

During the recording, the sync must have been lost because when I went to post produce the show, one word of the speaker was extremely high-pitched - chipmunk-style, and I was able to fix it with either an alternate take from the rehearsal or by pitching it down the exact amount it was pitched up.

I didn't have much time to look for the cause, but I suspect it was some sort of sync issue. It scares me because I cannot hear this while the event is being recorded (listening back on Pro Tools I don't hear sync issues until I can play back the audio file). I don't know if this was due to the Word Clock or the Video Ref being lost for that brief bit. (Note: this was also the only bit of audio this happened on out of about 15 hours of recordings.) I also record with the session window open so I can monitor the "Locked" and "Speed Cal" indicators and from what I could tell they were both lit the whole way through.

Have any of you had a similar problem? What was the handling / fix? How can I prevent this from happening in the future?

Thanks very much in advance.

Answer (score 3):

I had something similar happen the other day. A region in PT displays like a normal old sound wave, but the second half plays back as an almighty blast of static. Weirdest thing I've seen in a while.

Comment: This has happened to me before. Relaunch the app. It has to do with the way Pro Tools references the file in session. This has always fixed that issue. The source files in the Audio Files folder always play fine by themselves as well....proof the source is good.

Comment: If there's on remaining ProTools issue which is the bane of my existance, it's this one.  It seemes to happen when a session sits idle for a long time (i.e. going to lunch).  Simply re-opening the session seems to temporarily slove it until it rears its head hours later if it sits idle again.

Answer (score 2):

it's called "bugs", i.e. software errors... all due respect but i'd never trust pro tools to record 15 hours of audio in sync to video ref, whatever the source.